# python list to dict weirdness

Tags: python, list, dictionary, zip

Got a complication with my python code.

```
print len(list1)
print len(list2)
dikt = dict(zip(list1,list2))
print len(dikt)
```

Gives:

```
>> 95
>> 95 
>> 26
```

Why does the dikt give me the value of 26 instead of 95, can add that the elements in the lists are not the same.
I am clueless.

Comment: Is this a guessing game? I guess that list1 contains single character strings that are either all uppercase or all lowercase letters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have repeated values in `list1`. A `dict` cannot have duplicated keys.

```
>>> list1 = [1, 1, 2]
>>> list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> dikt = dict(zip(list1,list2))
>>> print len(dikt)
2
>>> print dikt
{1: 'b', 2: 'c'}
```

Answer (score 2):

If there are duplicate entries in `list1`, each would only appear once in `dikt`.

If you wanted to preserve all values associated with those duplicated keys, you could do something like

```
import collections
dikt = collections.defaultdict(list)
list1 = [1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 20]
list2 = list(range(len(list1)))
for k, v in zip(list1, list2):
    dikt[k].append(v)
print(dikt)
```

This gives

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [0, 1], 2: [2, 4, 6], 3: [3], 20: [7], 5: [5]})
```